# How fetch data only if pool was almost empty?

Tags: java

My cron will fetch data from database then put them all to a pool such as Queue.
For example, the pool can has max size of 1000.
I have many workers to poll data from the pool then resolve it.

The problem is if I fetch more data from database only if the pool was empty, so all of my workers must to wait and do nothing. Well, i don't think it a good idea.
If I fetch data each 5 seconds for example, the pool still can be too full or too empty cause of the time that worker need to resolve each data is cannot estimated.

So, My question is how can I code another thread only run when the size of pool has 50% left?

I just ask for a solution. I haven't code any yet.

Comment: from design prospective, here's my 2 cents. You are using thread pool. So when you are polling db every time you must check number of available threads in pool and then you have same number (approx.) of records.

Comment: But above comment will only makes sense if your problem have only mentioned context. If it has larger scope then you need to come up design first and I am not sure if this is right place for this.

Comment: Thanks. I should make my problems clearer. I my opinion, i trying to create a new Queue that will trigger the fetching method when it just have 50% of pool size left in a new Thread. After some testing of performance and cases, i will show my code and please give me some help

Answer (score 0):

Not a comprehensive answer as more details may be required, but here are some ideas:

**Assuming that your pool of data and threads are in the same JVM, you may have several strategies to do so:**

- Poll your pool size, instead of directly polling the data: If the pool size is lower than a certain threshold, then fetch data, otherwise wait until next iteration.
- Limit the data to match your pool size (poolMaxSize - currentPoolSize): instead of loading a big chunk of data all the time, fetch only enough data to keep your pool as busy as possible. Then it won't matter whether it was "too busy" or "too empty"

Both options above requires a dedicated Thread to poll information.

**If you have control over your pool of data**, then maybe the "read" option your  workers use may evaluate a threshold and trigger a "fetch more" operation (if that makes any sense). This would remove the need of an additional Thread and make it a little more "event driven".

**Otherwise** it would be helpful to know more details about what your pool looks like (do you use Kafka, ActiveMQ, other technology to it) so people can come up with better ideas.